# Adding second ssd card to already dual booted pc (ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I currently have linux and windows installed on my pc with GRUB loader on linux.  I want to add a secondary ssd for windows and was wondering if windows disk management can take care of the addition or would linux affect anything.

Thank you

Comment: That is okay if you don't mind clicking F12 to select a drive each boot. I would remove the Ubuntu drive while installing Windows, Plug Ubuntu back in after, run `sudo update-grub`, and let the current grub look after bootloading.

Comment: Are you planning to move Windows to the new ssd or just use it for additional data storage? If it’s the latter Windows disk management can make partitions for Windows to use. It will not  affect Linux.  If it’s the former the comment above is good advice.